# I am trying to save the form data to database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to save user form data to database. I tried in these way but its not save anything i'm getting None value.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import Signup

from .models import Signup

def Sign_up(request):
username = request.POST.get('username')
mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number')
email = request.POST.get('email')
password = request.POST.get('password')
address = request.POST.get('address')
print("Hello form is submitted")
print(username)
print(mobile_number)
print(email)
print(password)
print(address)
post = Signup(username= username, mobile_number=mobile_number,email=email, 
               password=password, address=address)
post.save()
return render(request, 'sign_up/sign_up.html',{})
```

---

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Signup(models.Model):

username = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='SOME STRING', 
                              blank=True, null=True)
mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
address = models. CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
print("Hi")

def __str__(self):
    return self.username or ''

def __str__(self):
    return self.mobile_number or ''

def __str__(self):
    return self.email or ''

def __str__(self):
    return self.password or ''

def __str__(self):
    return self.address or ''
```

---

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Signup

class SignupForm(forms.Form):

username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
mobile_number = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True)
password = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

## I'm getting like this

Django version 2.2, using settings 'project.settings'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Hello form is submitted

None

None

None

None

None

[01/May/2019 22:39:18] "GET /signup/? HTTP/1.1" 200 3360

Comment: In what way? Please share your attempt.

Comment: your console shows you're sending a GET request, not a POST request. Check your template and make sure your form has `method="post"` set. Also it's good practice to check that in your view: `if request.method == "POST"` before attempting to fetch data from `request.POST` and saving something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a Signup object in a wrong manner, create it like this:

you can create model form instead like this:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        fields = ('username', )#pass fields here
```

and in your view you get the values entered by user like this:

```
formToSave = SignupForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
       if formToSave.is_valid():
         product = formToSave.save()
```

but if you don't want to use the model form you can create the object `Signup` and then save it as you are doing but make sure before creating the object you are getting all the form values in your views by printing them(as you are already doing)

```
post = Signup.objects.create(username= username, mobile_number=mobile_number,email=email, 
                   password=password, address=address)
```

then save it

```
post.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this model in production be careful.

Storing non hashed password is a really bad practice.

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel here.

There is several ways to manage the User model in django.
If you decide to create your own User system, please read this first:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/

## Extending the existing User model

There are two ways to extend the default User model without substituting your own model. If the changes you need are purely behavioral, and don’t require any change to what is stored in the database, you can create a proxy model based on User. This allows for any of the features offered by proxy models including default ordering, custom managers, or custom model methods.

If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a OneToOneField to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user. For example you might create an Employee model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

## Using a custom user model when starting a project

If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Don’t forget to point AUTH_USER_MODEL to it. Do this before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.

Also, register the model in the app’s admin.py

**Further in the Doc**

## Specifying a custom user model

> When you start your project with a custom user model, stop to consider
>   if this is the right choice for your project.
>
> Keeping all user related information in one model removes the need for
>   additional or more complex database queries to retrieve related
>   models. On the other hand, it may be more suitable to store
>   app-specific user information in a model that has a relation with your
>   custom user model. That allows each app to specify its own user data
>   requirements without potentially conflicting or breaking assumptions
>   by other apps. It also means that you would keep your user model as
>   simple as possible, focused on authentication, and following the
>   minimum requirements Django expects custom user models to meet.
>
> If you use the default authentication backend, then your model must
>   have a single unique field that can be used for identification
>   purposes. This can be a username, an email address, or any other
>   unique attribute. A non-unique username field is allowed if you use a
>   custom authentication backend that can support it.
>
> The easiest way to construct a compliant custom user model is to
>   inherit from AbstractBaseUser. AbstractBaseUser provides the core
>   implementation of a user model, including hashed passwords and
>   tokenized password resets. You must then provide some key
>   implementation details

As a reference here is the doc page about user authentication: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/

If you want to choose the default django User system: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/ and more info about the default user api : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/